# Allow div content to be 'infront' of an overlay positioned with ::after

Tags: html, css

I have a footer which is purple, but then also have an overlay image for the footer which I am showing using a ::after selector:

```
footer::after {
    content: "";
    background: url(/wp-content/themes/atheme/images/footermask.png);
    opacity: 0.1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

I have the usual links and social items in the footer, but the ::after mask is causing them to not be clickable. As a work around I positioned the elements absolutely and gave them a higher z index but its causing other issues with position and I feel its not the right way to go about it.

How can these elements NOT be absolutely positioned, yet still come above the overlay ::after mask?

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/g88ucp7k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of, remove the `z-index: 100;` from the `::after`
- Wrap your footer content inside a `position:relative` DIV
- Set `z-index` to that content in order to overlay... the overlay :)

```css
footer {
  padding: 50px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  overflow: hidden;
}
footer .content{ /* ADDED */
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
footer a{
  color: white;
}
footer::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(http://cdn1.bestpsdfreebies.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/shards_pattern.jpg);
  opacity: 0.4;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: 100; REMOVED */    
  height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="content">
        <a href="#">A link</a>
    </div>
</footer>
```